# JavaFx Scenbuilder ImageView Quality

Tags: java, css, javafx, scenebuilder

Hello guys i have been using JavaFx scene builder to build a gui that contains a few png pictures.

So far  i have been using labels and then enlarged them to fit the picture(so that the picture is visible. however this solution is not satisfying because i need to create x amount of these pictures when ever someone new connects to my program. i therefore tried to experiament with the use of Imageview however it seems that the quaility of the picture is worse when i use Imageview. Does anyone know either A. how i can make a label and set it to a certain size with a picutre and make sure that the new picture is always 1 certain size that fits overall

or B improve the quaility of ImageView or know if there is any better option that i could use to show small pictures of my characters :)

Best regards Marc Rasmussen

Ps. if you need a image of my program then i will gladly add it in a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final ImageView anImage = new ImageView();   
        Image image1 = new Image(StackedBarM.class.getResourceAsStream("a.png"));
        anImage.setImage(image1);
        anImage.setFitWidth(40);
        anImage.setPreserveRatio(true);
        anImage.setSmooth(true); 
        anImage.setCache(true);
```

For me, it's showing very little difference in quality after downsizing it. You can always re-size the images & save it in high quality in PS for your required dimensions.

Comment: for me it sadly Shows a huge difference and there is no way to do this with high Quality, nothing Change since almost 5 years ...